# Bootstrap LightBox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, lightbox

I am having difficulty with the bootstrap lightbox plugin.  I got the code from

http://jbutz.github.io/bootstrap-lightbox/#home

I would like to have it where a user can click a link and then be shown all the images in the lightbox.  Right now I have the following code:

```
<div id="demoLightbox" class="lightbox hide fade"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class='lightbox-content'>
  <% for picture in @gallery %>
    <%= image_tag picture.image_url.to_s %>
    <div class="lightbox-caption"><p><%= picture.caption %></p></div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I am using CarrierWave for images and have a caption for each image.  Right now each image is being displayed on the page (I do not want that) and images are not clickable, as well as the entire lightbox only has one caption.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have only defined the hidden div that is popped when you run the Lightbox code.  If you look at the page source, you'll see that the whole Lightbox code section looks like this:

```
<div class="example">
  <ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="span2">
      <a data-toggle="lightbox" href="#demoLightbox" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="assets/img/small.png" alt="Click to view the lightbox">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="demoLightbox" class="lightbox hide fade"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class='lightbox-content'>
      <img src="assets/img/large.png">
      <div class="lightbox-caption"><p>Your caption here</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice how there is a `ul` of clickable thumbnails that have the `data-toggle="lightbox"` attribute and link to the div containing the fullsize picture.

Try adding the clickable thumbnail with the above attributes to your code.